# ECMAScript 6 exception when evaluating default parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Consider the following code:

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 1;
  }

  method1() {
    throw new Error();
  }

  method2(b = this.method1()) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      console.log(this);  // logs undefined
      resolve(this.a);
    });
  }
}

const t = new Test();
t.method2()
.then((r) => {
   console.log('result', r);
})
.catch((e) => {
   console.log('error', e);
});
```

Note how `method1`, which is used as the default parameter for `method2`, throws an exception.

When using [Babel](https://babeljs.io) to transpile this code, `console.log(this)` shows that `this` becomes `undefined`, but no exception is raised. Is this standard behaviour (and if yes, what is the reasoning behind it) or a bug in Babel?

Comment: Seems to me that an error is being thrown, it's just that Babel has code in place that's catching it.  Chrome is breaking on this line: `if (error) throw error;` (part of Babel code) where `error` is being reported as `Error at Test.method1 (eval at <anonymous> .....`

Comment: [Here's the transpiled code](http://jsfiddle.net/b4g2fw9g/) in jsfiddle - again the method is throwing an error, and you see no console logs.  Are you seeing something different?  If so, where and how are you executing the transpiled code?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I have a similar code in an application, which fails when trying to access a property on this at the line where I have the `console.log` (`cannot access property foo of undefined`).

Comment: Seems that the code you have elsewhere isn't quite the same as what you've reduced it to here then

Comment: [Here](http://bit.ly/1KUez0s) is the exact code from your question in the Babel REPL. Notice in the console `Uncaught Error: method1`. Which is correct. You should go back to your app and try to find the difference in that code and what you have here